# What would trained dolphins actually be capable of?

Tags: science-based, aquaculture

I was quite surprised recently to find out that trained dolphins *are* used by the US Navy (as well as other countries') for a variety of purposes, including search and rescue, detection of submarines, detection of divers (assumedly spies), and mine identification.

I wouldn't expect them to do bomb disposal or anything, but it got me thinking.

In my fictional setting, it's a somewhat post-apocalyptic setting, where the people in question have access to modern *knowledge* but not modern *manufacturing* or *infrastructure*. Thus they have to sort of invent a lot of "primitive" ways of doing things, even if they're inspired by things that used to be done with plastics and steel and so on. Also, in my fictional setting, the people live in permanent structures separated by water (think Venice without all the sidewalks and bridges, and wider canals), so there's a lot of short-distance swimming, little rowboats and kayaks, and so on.

But I was thinking about dolphins, and wondering what could they could be trained to do. Could they ...

- Pull swimmers? Actual rescue of, say, trapped or drowning people?
- Pull freight, like little barges? How much? My gut says not very much weight, but I have no idea how I would look into that.
- Deliver packages, like little satchels attached with a harness? Could we communicate with them effectively?
- Hunt and *retrieve the kill*?
- Some other clever task I haven't thought of?

As far as I can quickly google, the navy is using them for navy things, but others aren't, because honestly, we have better solutions for all this stuff (maybe not search and rescue) or a lack of need for it (because we don't live in and around the ocean to this degree).

Comment: [Dolphins and humans work together to catch fish in Brazil](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/dolphins-and-humans-work-together-to-catch-fish-in-brazil-180981553/%23:~:text%3DBut%2520the%2520humans%2520get%2520help,they%2520should%2520cast%2520their%2520nets.&ved=2ahUKEwiLs_Cfiv-EAxUIQEEAHTXSA7cQFnoECBIQBQ&usg=AOvVaw3niHVNuXzi9HQNbf9uj-64) You might find that useful, a dolphin could only carry one small fish back at a time, so this seems a far more efficient and time effective way to go about it.

Comment: I recommend reading The Neptune Project by Polly Holyoke. I’m not sure how much of the dolphin abilities are realistic (e.g. the dolphins & humans are telepathic, but you could train the dolphins to do most of the “talking” with body language/hand signals) , but it involves people and dolphins working together in a semi-apocalyptic future.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah some of this could definitely be possible. Dolphins are incredibly smart creatures, and they should be able to be trained to pull people or other objects. Of course, they would have to be able to be directed in some manner while under water. One option would be to have each dolphin trained to report to one position (a cave, submarine, shipwreck, etc.). I think this would definitely be possible, since you can easily do the same for dogs.

Comment: This is better put as a comment, as there is the basis of an answer. However, since you’re presently unable to put it as a comment (I think minimum rep needed is 100), you just need to add some extra information to flesh it out.